# Correct place to declare a object in C#

Tags: c#, class, object, visual-studio-2012, viewcontroller

I came across the following situation. 
I have a lot of class files in my project, and, as the project was growing, new functions were being created, but without the correct code review. So, we have some duplicated objects (to access the database, like a controller) being created around the same class, but we don't know if it is better to create only one global object or if we should leave them inside the function, because sometimes the code will not reaches that function, so the object will never be created. If it is global, it will be created every time.

Example:

```
namespace EventWorks.View
{
    public partial class Event : System.Web.UI.Page, ISecurityRules
    {
        protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventController EventCtrl = new EventController();

            //some code
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventController EventCtrl = new EventController();

            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, where should I create these objects? It's better to create it globally? Or leave it inside the function and let the garbage collector take care of it? Or make a big analysis and check for every file which option is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where should I create these objects?

That really depends on the responsibility of the object, the thread-safety considerations (if there are any), and cost of creating such a global member. There is no *"yes make it global"* solution to all your problems. You should definitely analyze all your members and decide for each one if it is OK to make them globally available and what effects it would have on your system. For example, keeping a `DbContext` alive in memory as a single instance would be considered bad practice, since it isn't thread-safe.

If you're only worried about unnecessary objects being created, you can always use the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class which will make sure the value is only lazily initialized on the first access:

```
private readonly Lazy<EventController> eventController = new
                 Lazy<EventController>(x => new EventController(), isThreadSafe: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If used in multiple functions it can be declared on class level like this (thats not global, but class level):

```
namespace EventWorks.View
{
    public partial class Event : System.Web.UI.Page, ISecurityRules
    {
        EventController _eventController = new EventController();

        protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _eventController.DoSomething();
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _eventController.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

It can be initiliased in constructor also, or it can be injected via dependency injection (Constructor, Interface, setter injection), I guess it all depends what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Often a controller keeps some information on the object status. I.e., whether the object is new or whether it has been loaded from a DB, whether it has pending changes or not and so on.

Therefore it seems more logical to have a controller that has the same life-time as the object (it would be created once per object).

If the controller does not store any object dependent stuff, it could be created once per application lifetime. In this case you could make it a singleton.

```
public class EventController
{
    public static readonly EventController Instance = new EventController();

    private EventController()
    {
        // Make constuctor private, so the class cannot be instantiated elsewhere.
    }

    // Implement functionality here...
}
```

call it like this:

```
EventController.Instance.DoSomething();
```

Comment: this is static declaration, not singleton, singleton is an alternative to static

Comment: There are different ways of implementing singletons. The point is that you have a non-static class which is instantiated exactly once. Even if you implement it by using an IOC container, you will need to have a static access to this container. There must be something static there, that allows you to access the singleton.

Comment: exactly, however in your example, u made nothing like singleton...any of the 4 most common implementations of it

Comment: "Singleton" defines how an object behaves, not how it is implemented.